# Levi-Civita in 4 dimensions to 3 dimensions

Tags: conventions, spacetime-dimensions, poincare-symmetry

i was calculating Pauli ljubanski vector in the case of massive particles . considering the rest frame(m,0,0,0) $W_i =-(m/2)\epsilon_{0ijk} M^{jk}$.
I got $\epsilon_{0ijk}=\epsilon_{ijk}$. so, $W_i=-mJ_i$. Wut i saw in one reference that $\epsilon_{0ijk}=-\epsilon_{ijk}$. Which one is right?